# In FT2Font: Can not load face

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot a bar. But it shows Runtime error, and shows In FT2Font: Can not load face. at the Botton. 
I have tried uninstall and install it again. And tried another method, but still can not work. I think the code is right, because I successfully run it on a windows laptop. And my jupyter notebook is for Mac python 2.7.

The code is as following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
obj = pd.Series([4, 7, -5, 3])
print type(obj)
obj
%matplotlib inline
obj.plot(kind = 'bar', figsize=[5,4])
```

But it shows some error :

```
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1114e69d0>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    332                 pass
    333             else:
--> 334                 return printer(obj)
    335             # Finally look for special method names
    336             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in <lambda>(fig)
    238 
    239     if 'png' in formats:
--> 240         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    241     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    242         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    122 
    123     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 124     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    125     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    126     if fmt == 'svg':

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.pyc in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2206                     orientation=orientation,
   2207                     dryrun=True,
-> 2208                     **kwargs)
   2209                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2210                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    505 
    506     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 507         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    508         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    509         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in draw(self)
    428             if toolbar:
    429                 toolbar.set_cursor(cursors.WAIT)
--> 430             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    431         finally:
    432             if toolbar:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1293 
   1294             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1295                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1296 
   1297             renderer.close_group('figure')

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.pyc in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    136     if not_composite or not has_images:
    137         for a in artists:
--> 138             a.draw(renderer)
    139     else:
    140         # Composite any adjacent images together

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2397             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2398 
-> 2399         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2400 
   2401         renderer.close_group('axes')

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.pyc in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    136     if not_composite or not has_images:
    137         for a in artists:
--> 138             a.draw(renderer)
    139     else:
    140         # Composite any adjacent images together

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1133         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1134         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
-> 1135                                                                 renderer)
   1136 
   1137         for tick in ticks_to_draw:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
   1073         for tick in ticks:
   1074             if tick.label1On and tick.label1.get_visible():
-> 1075                 extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1076                 ticklabelBoxes.append(extent)
   1077             if tick.label2On and tick.label2.get_visible():

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    968             raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
    969 
--> 970         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    971         x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
    972         x, y = self.get_transform().transform_point((x, y))

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    352         tmp, lp_h, lp_bl = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent('lp',
    353                                                          self._fontproperties,
--> 354                                                          ismath=False)
    355         offsety = (lp_h - lp_bl) * self._linespacing
    356 

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    233 
    234         flags = get_hinting_flag()
--> 235         font = self._get_agg_font(prop)
    236         font.set_text(s, 0.0, flags=flags)  # the width and height of unrotated string
    237         w, h = font.get_width_height()

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in _get_agg_font(self, prop)
    270         font = get_font(
    271             fname,
--> 272             hinting_factor=rcParams['text.hinting_factor'])
    273 
    274         font.clear()

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports/functools_lru_cache.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwds)
    135                         stats[HITS] += 1
    136                         return result
--> 137                 result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
    138                 with lock:
    139                     root, = nonlocal_root

RuntimeError: In FT2Font: Can not load face.

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x1114e6290>
```

I have tried uninstall it. and another code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
obj = pd.Series([4, 7, -5, 3])
print type(obj)
obj
plt.plot(obj)
plt.show()
```

And still show errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    332                 pass
    333             else:
--> 334                 return printer(obj)
    335             # Finally look for special method names
    336             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in <lambda>(fig)
    238 
    239     if 'png' in formats:
--> 240         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    241     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    242         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    122 
    123     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 124     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    125     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    126     if fmt == 'svg':

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.pyc in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2206                     orientation=orientation,
   2207                     dryrun=True,
-> 2208                     **kwargs)
   2209                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2210                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    505 
    506     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 507         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    508         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    509         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in draw(self)
    428             if toolbar:
    429                 toolbar.set_cursor(cursors.WAIT)
--> 430             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    431         finally:
    432             if toolbar:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc in draw(self, renderer)
   1293 
   1294             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1295                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   1296 
   1297             renderer.close_group('figure')

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.pyc in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    136     if not_composite or not has_images:
    137         for a in artists:
--> 138             a.draw(renderer)
    139     else:
    140         # Composite any adjacent images together

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.pyc in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2397             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2398 
-> 2399         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
   2400 
   2401         renderer.close_group('axes')

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.pyc in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    136     if not_composite or not has_images:
    137         for a in artists:
--> 138             a.draw(renderer)
    139     else:
    140         # Composite any adjacent images together

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.pyc in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     53                 renderer.start_filter()
     54 
---> 55             return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     56         finally:
     57             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1133         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1134         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
-> 1135                                                                 renderer)
   1136 
   1137         for tick in ticks_to_draw:

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.pyc in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
   1073         for tick in ticks:
   1074             if tick.label1On and tick.label1.get_visible():
-> 1075                 extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1076                 ticklabelBoxes.append(extent)
   1077             if tick.label2On and tick.label2.get_visible():

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    968             raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
    969 
--> 970         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    971         x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
    972         x, y = self.get_transform().transform_point((x, y))

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.pyc in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    352         tmp, lp_h, lp_bl = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent('lp',
    353                                                          self._fontproperties,
--> 354                                                          ismath=False)
    355         offsety = (lp_h - lp_bl) * self._linespacing
    356 

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    233 
    234         flags = get_hinting_flag()
--> 235         font = self._get_agg_font(prop)
    236         font.set_text(s, 0.0, flags=flags)  # the width and height of unrotated string
    237         w, h = font.get_width_height()

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.pyc in _get_agg_font(self, prop)
    270         font = get_font(
    271             fname,
--> 272             hinting_factor=rcParams['text.hinting_factor'])
    273 
    274         font.clear()

/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports/functools_lru_cache.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwds)
    135                         stats[HITS] += 1
    136                         return result
--> 137                 result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
    138                 with lock:
    139                     root, = nonlocal_root

RuntimeError: In FT2Font: Can not load face.

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x113232250>
```

Comment: Have you considered accepting the upvoted answer, because it seems to work?

Answer (score 10):

I was facing same issue while using anaconda and spyder with python 3+ on MacOS.
I am not sure if this solution would work for you but i solved it by deleting all files and folder in:

```
/Users/YOUR_USER/.matplotlib
```

and then uninstalling and reinstalling *'matplotlib'* from my environment in *Anaconda Navigator*.

Comment: I have the same set up, instead of deleting and reinstalling though.  I just added the font to my system, which caused it to be added to the `/Users/YOUR_USER/.matplotlib/fontlist-v{version_number}.json` file.  Which then in my python script, I updated the fname to match the .json file.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this error - looking through the matplotlib debug logs, everything seemed ok. However, when I checked the path of the font that had been selected, the file size was 0KB. Maybe it got corrupted when matplotlib was being installed.

Copying the font file from another machine into the font directory fixed the problem.

Fyi, the path is `%CONDA_ENV%\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf` (I'm using conda on Windows, but the path should be the same relative to your site-packages directory on your local installation). Reinstalling matplotlib will fix the issue, but it's worth checking this folder, just in case the issue is just one bad font file.